# Groupby number of hours in a month in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Could someone please guide how to groupby no. of hours from hourly based index to find how many hours of null values are there in a specific month? Therefore, I am thinking of having a dataframe with monthly based index.

Below given is the dataframe which has timestamp as index and another column with has occassionally null values.

| timestamp | rel_humidity |
| --- | --- |
| 1999-09-27 05:00:00 | 82.875 |
| 1999-09-27 06:00:00 | 83.5 |
| 1999-09-27 07:00:00 | 83.0 |
| 1999-09-27 08:00:00 | 80.6 |
| 1999-09-27 09:00:00 | nan |
| 1999-09-27 10:00:00 | nan |
| 1999-09-27 11:00:00 | nan |
| 1999-09-27 12:00:00 | nan |

I tried this but the resulting dataframe is not what I expected.

gap_in_month = OG_1998_2022_gaps.groupby(OG_1998_2022_gaps.index.month, OG_1998_2022_gaps.index.year).count()

I always struggle with groupby in function. Therefore, highly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need `0` if no missing value per month create mask by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html), convert `DatetimeIndex` to month periods by [`DatetimeIndex.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html) and aggregate `sum` - `True`s of mask are processing like `1` or alternative with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
gap_in_month = (OG_1998_2022_gaps['rel_humidity'].isna()
                 .groupby(OG_1998_2022_gaps.index.to_period('m')).sum())

gap_in_month = (OG_1998_2022_gaps['rel_humidity'].isna()
                 .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='m')).sum())
```

If need only matched rows solution is similar, but first filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then aggregate counts by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
gap_in_month = (OG_1998_2022_gaps[OG_1998_2022_gaps['rel_humidity'].isna()]
                 .groupby(OG_1998_2022_gaps.index.to_period('m')).size())

gap_in_month = (OG_1998_2022_gaps[OG_1998_2022_gaps['rel_humidity'].isna()]
                 .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='m')).size())
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and detailed response @jezrael! It works perfectly and got to know about GroupBy.size which I had no idea about. Anyways thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to groupby, but (in my opinion) much nicer, is to use [`pd.Series.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html):

```
import pandas as pd

# Some sample data with a DatetimeIndex:
series = pd.Series(
    np.random.choice([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, np.nan], size=2185),
    index=pd.date_range(start="1999-09-26", end="1999-12-26", freq="H")
)

# Solution:
series.isna().resample("M").sum()

# Note that GroupBy.count and Resampler.count count the number of non-null values,
# whereas you seem to be looking for the opposite :)
```

In your case:

```
OG_1998_2022_gaps['rel_humidity'].isna().resample("M").sum()
```

Comment: Thank you @Chrysophylaxs for the alternative. It works perfectly. I am fairly new to the coding world, please excuse using count() rather than using sum(). Anyways thanks!!